# Which scope should I use to ask user for permission to read-only repo (private and public) with Github API?

Tags: api, github

According to [GitHub API documentation](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-integrations/setting-up-and-registering-oauth-apps/about-scopes-for-oauth-apps/), I can't get what scope I should use to ask to user to let me download his public/private repo, in *read-only* manner.
Currently I'm using `repo` but as you can read in the docs it:

> Grants read/write access to code, commit statuses, invitations,
>   collaborators, adding team memberships, and deployment statuses for
>   public and private repositories and organizations.

But I don't want to ask to the user the permission to *write on his repos*!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was [requested in 2015](https://github.com/jollygoodcode/jollygoodcode.github.io/issues/6), and two years later, the [GitHub Platform Roadmap](https://developer.github.com/early-access/platform-roadmap/) does mention a "Granular access permissions".

But for now, read-only access is not yet part of the available scopes.

A possible workaround would be to [setup a mirror repo](https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository/), and on each commit on the first original repo, force pushing (overriding) said commit to the second repo (obliterating any write/modification done on that second repo)